# array values are not printed in normal run, but printing in debug mode in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i wanted to paste some values from every sheet of the workbook to the last sheet using array, so i wrote this code, but the code is not pasting anything but when i run using two break points in each loop then it is pasting i don't know what is the problem please help me with this issue, i have been facing this issue for a long time haven't got any solution

```
Sub d()
Dim tags() As Variant

x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ReDim tags(x)
For i = 1 To x  
   tags(i) = Sheets(i).Range("r14").Value
Next i
Sheets(x).Activate
For i = 1 To x
   Cells(i, 1).Value = tags(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: remove `Sheets(x).Activate` and then change `Cells(i, 1).Value = tags(i)` to `Sheets(x).Cells(i, 1).Value = tags(i)`. Now please can you try it?

Comment: thankyou for your reply but when i try that it is not pasting, it is pasting only blanks, the value is getting copied to the array but the pasting loop is not working , in the above code i kept break point at sheets(x).activate and when i run the program it is not pasting but i have to run the below "for loop" for one value and then if i run it completely it is pasting all values , when i run it without doing this step is simply doesn't paste the values , i want to know what is the reason and what mistake i am doing can anyone please clarify it, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

### Backup Cell Values

**A More Robust Solution**

```
Option Explicit

Sub BackupCellValues()
    
    Const sAddr As String = "R14" ' Source Cell Address
    Const dAddr As String = "A1" ' Destination First Cell Address
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If the workbook containing these worksheets is also the one containing
    ' this code, using 'ThisWorkbook' instead of 'ActiveWorkbook' is a must.
    
    Dim swsCount As Long: swsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count - 1 ' except the last
    ' You need at least two worksheets to make this work hence:
    If swsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' highly unlikely, but why take a chance?
    ' Define a 2D ('...,...') one-based ('1 To...') one-column array ('1 To 1').
    Dim sTags As Variant: ReDim sTags(1 To swsCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Write from source to array by looping.
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To swsCount
        sTags(n, 1) = wb.Worksheets(n).Range(sAddr).Value
    Next n
    ' at this point, 'n = swsCount + 1'
    
    ' Write from array to destination in one go (no loop necessary).
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(n)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dAddr).Resize(swsCount)
    drg.Value = sTags

End Sub
```

**A Quick Fix (not recommended because it works until it doesn't)**

```
'Option Explicit

Sub BackupCellValuesUnreliable()
    
    x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ReDim tags(1 To x - 1)
    
    For i = 1 To x - 1
        tags(i) = Worksheets(i).Range("R14").Value
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To x - 1
        ' Note that you can move the following line to the previous loop.
        Worksheets(x).Cells(i, 1).Value = tags(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply but i am facing the same problem with this quick fix code, i did step through all the steps but it is not pasting but when i remove worksheets(x) and added worksheets(x).active before the "for loop" and run one loop for 1st value and after i hit complete run then it is pasting the whole values , if don't run the single loop using step through then it doesn't paste, same problem as my code, can you please tell me what is the reason , thankyou for your reply

Comment: thankyou for the code backupcellvalues() but i not getting the results, i don't know what mistake i am doing i face this issue many times but i will run that code using debug mode, i don't know what mistake i am doing, please everyone help me with that, thankyou

Comment: As I wrote in one of the comments of `BackupCellValues`: *If the workbook containing these worksheets is also the one containing this code, using 'ThisWorkbook' instead of 'ActiveWorkbook' is a must.* Have you tried `ThisWorkbook` or are the aforementioned (the code and the worksheets) in different workbooks? BTW if you're getting an error, please share the error number and its description. Please do clarify because both codes work on my end. If the problem persists, try recreating the workbook, because it may be corrupt.

Comment: thankyou for your kind reply i tried in another workbook similar to that workbook both code are working fine,but in the workbook which i am facing the problem my code and in the code backupcellvaluesUnreliable() i added the step sheets(x).activate and i performed those debug steps and it is working, the problem is with the workbook which i am using other than that code is perfect, but i wanted to know what is the problem in that workbook and why VBA is behaving like this continuationNextComment:

Comment: continuation:  , the workbook that i am using is protected workbook but i don't think that will impose any problem becoz i tried it with another protected workbook it is working fine, what could be the possible problem?, i just wanted to know , please help me with it , when i tried  the code backupcellvalues() in debug mode it is not even able to get the values in the array ,it is just getting the blank values , i don't know the problem in the workbook ,can you please tell me why vba is behaving like that , thankyou so much for your kind reply